# delayed_job daemon killed with error "Lost connection to MySQL server."

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I have an application with the delayed jobs daemonized.
This daemonized delayed jobs process is being killed often.

But, when I invoke `rake jobs:work` manually, the corresponding delayedjob process doesn't get killed.

I am experiencing two scenarios with this issue:

The first scenario has the error listed in the log file

```
ImportSQLJob failed with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query: DELETE FROM `delayed_jobs` WHERE (`delayed_jobs`.`id` = 93528940) - 0 failed attempts
```

And `delayed_job` has been locked by the system.

The pid created exists in the applications "/tmp/pids/" folder but upon the checking the system process using `ps -aux`, couldn't find the process mentioned.

In the second scenario, the daemonized `delayed_jobs` process was killed without any errors in the log file, but here the jobs are not being locked and couldn't find the pids in the application's /tmp/pids/ directory. This is same as the one mentioned in the [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delayed_job/QV1WnmHb7PI). In that thread, Andrew Havens mentioned, regarding a patch for the daemons gem, that the `srand()` function was causing the issue. I couldn't find the patch made by him as the Rubyforge website is down permanently.

Upon checking the other posts in Stack Overflow, I suspect the issue to be either with the daemons gem or the mysql2 gem, but couldn't come to a conclusion because of my limited Rails knowledge.

And earlier I had a MySQL server go away issue and I added `reconnect: true` to my database.yml file which fixed that issue.

My production environment is:

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Ruby version:1.9.3-p429
```

The gems which I use for my application are:

```
actionmailer (3.2.2)
actionpack (3.2.2)
activemodel (3.2.2)
activerecord (3.2.2)
activeresource (3.2.2)
activesupport (3.2.2)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.1)
choice (0.1.6)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
composite_primary_keys (5.0.8)
country-select (1.1.1)
daemon_controller (1.1.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
delayed_job (3.0.4)
delayed_job_active_record (0.3.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
eventmachine (1.0.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
faraday (0.8.4)
fastthread (1.0.7)
google-spreadsheet-ruby (0.3.0)
google_drive (0.3.2)
hike (1.2.1)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.3)
jquery-ui-rails (4.1.2)
json (1.7.5)
jwt (0.1.5)
libv8 (3.11.8.13 x86-linux)
log4r (1.1.10)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.7)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-ssh (2.9.0)
nokogiri (1.5.5)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.8.0)
passenger (3.0.18)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.2)
railties (3.2.2)
rake (10.0.4, 10.0.1)
rdoc (3.12)
ref (1.0.2)
roo (1.10.1)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.5)
rubygems-bundler (1.2.0)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sass (3.2.3)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
spreadsheet (0.7.4)
sprockets (2.1.3)
therubyracer (0.11.4)
thin (1.5.0)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
todonotes (0.1.0)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
will_paginate (3.0.3)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
```

And the database.yml file is:

```
production:

adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
database: smt_production
pool: 5
username: ****
password: ****
reconnect: true
```

Comment: Please read through the help for formatting a question. It helps us help you if the question is formatted for readability.

Comment: Thank you for formatting my question..